# What was a century called before it was called "century"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-requests, middle-english

The term ***[century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=century)*** in the more common connotation that refers to a period of 100 years is relatively recent:

> - The Modern English meaning is attested from 1650s, ***short for century of years (1620s)***. (Etymonline)
> - From Middle English ***[centuria](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?size=First%20100&type=orths&q1=centurie&rgxp=constrained)*** ‎
>   (a) A division of the Roman army: a century; (b) a Roman land measure. (Middle English Dictionary)

It appears that the Middle English term was used only to refer  to  a Roman army company  consisting of approximately 100 men and to a land measure, and  I can find no evidence it was used to refer to a cycle of 100 years.

What term or expression was used to refer to a period of 100 years or to a specific century, the 11th or the 12th for instance in Middle English and/or in   Shakespeare's  times?

Comment: maybe just 'hundred years', as in [the hundred years' war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years%27_War)

Comment: some book results for 'hundred years': https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hundred%20years%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1500,cd_max:1610&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I wonder whether there was enough of a need for a specific word meaning a period of exactly one hundred that such a word existed. I’ll bet they used something like *age, era, eon, epoch*. I’m trying to think of some work in Middle English that might contain such a word. Modern Romance languages all use a word descended from Latin *saeculum* (IT *secolo*, PT *século*, FR *siècle*, OC *sègle*, ES *siglo*) but the modern sense of “century” is much more restricted than the original, which was often a more general term for ages. Middle English borrowed Old French *siecle* but that’s now obsolete.

Comment: wait, could the general populace even count to 100 back then? lol, serious question though, maybe that's why there was no term for it before the Renaissance...@tchrist, maybe you're right about *siècle* being the word the English elite used back then, since they would have had the education in French

Comment: @V0ight - on your first point, do general populace nowadays know what years the 15th century, for instance, refer to?

Comment: There may have been an occasional need to refer to a period of 100 years, but the idea of talking about "the xxxth century" is part of a view of history which did not arise until around that time.

Comment: @ColinFine - that is very interesting and plausible, evidence to support it would be helpful for general usage.

Comment: @Josh61 ~ touché...I think to answer this question we'd have to look somewhere in Chaucer's output, considering he was basically the progenitor of Middle English vernacular at a time when French and Latin were the dominant literary languages. So if there is a term other than 'hundred years' it would likely be found in one of his books.

Comment: @Josh61: I was afraid you'd ask that. I've been racking my brains to think where I might find clear evidence. I think most of the evidence is negative: ancient and mediaeval texts rarely even give dates, and if they do they're often relative to local events such as the accession of rulers. They might characterise a period as "the reign of X", but I don't think they had the concept of a particular century as a classification, nor of the succession of centuries.

Comment: @V0ight - we don't need to go as back as Chaucer, what expression Shakespeare used , if he used it, to refer to a century would be illuminating.

Comment: @V0ight I very strongly disagree that Chaucer was basically the progenitor of Middle English. Both *Cursor Mundi* and *Ancrene Riwle* were extremely important sources, and you have various other writers like the Gawain poet. Per the OED: [the surviving Middle English material is dominated by regional variation, and by (sometimes extreme) variation in how the same underlying linguistic units are represented in writing.](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-time/middle-english-an-overview/)

Comment: @tchrist ~ well Chaucer was the one that single-handedly popularized it with the academics; the other two you mentioned are anonymous which shows you that they weren't taken as seriously, despite the quality of their work.

Comment: If you want an excuse to bump the question, there's a typo in the question. It's small, and I don't think anyone's noticed but it's there. It's "..Shakespeare's time.." (not *times* as in *i tempi di Shakespeare*) I think it should be singular because we're talking about a single era, he lived in a specific period of time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -      You appear to be right: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Shakespeare%27s+time%2C+Shakespeare%27s+times+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CShakespeare%20%27s%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShakespeare%20%27s%20times%3B%2Cc0 - but "*SHAKESPEARE'S LIFE AND TIMES*" by the Royal Shakespeare Company : https://www.rsc.org.uk/shakespeares-life-and-times

Comment: I can't explain why the second option is correct... EDIT: Maybe it's a binomial/idiom thing; ["The Life And Times"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+life+and+times%2Cthe+life+and+time&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20life%20and%20times%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20life%20and%20time%3B%2Cc0) is a fixed expression. But it's nice to know I'm right about the tiny mishap/typo in your question. If you want to leave it, maybe you could tag your Q with etymology?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A *century* is equivalent to ***hundred years*** and the  origin of ***hundred*** dates back to Old English

> **hundred**
>   From Old English *hundred*, from Proto-Germanic * *hundaradą*, from * *hundą* (from Proto-Indo-European *ḱm̥tóm) + * *radą* ‎(“count”). Compare West Frisian *hûndert*, Dutch *honderd*, Low German *hunnert*, *hunnerd*, German *Hundert*, Danish *hundred*.
>
> **Old English**
>   From Proto-Germanic *hundaradą ‎(“telling of 100”), from *hundą (< Proto-Indo-European *ḱm̥tóm) + *radą ‎(“count”). Cognate with Old Frisian hundred, Old Saxon *hunderod*, Middle Dutch *hondert* (Dutch honderd), Old High German *hundert* (German Hundert), Old Norse *hundrað* ‎(“120; 100”) (Swedish *hundra* ‎(“100”)).
>
> **hunnert**
>    Numeral
>   hunnert ‎(*plural* hunnerts)
>
> 1. *Eye dialect* spelling of **hundred**.
>
> **year**
>   From Middle English [*yeer*, *yere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/year#Etymology), from **Old English** *ġēr*, *ġēar* ‎(“year”),
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hundred#Etymology)

From [*On the interaction between
constructional & lexical change
Copular, Passive and related Constructions in
Old and Middle English*](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/270027/1/Peter%2BPetr%25C3%25A9)

> - Ær ðam ðe Romeburh getimbred wære **eahta** **< hund > wintra**, mid ...
>     *translated*
>     before that that Rome built were **eight hundred winters** with ...
> - þa beoð on lenge hundteontiges fotmæla lange & fiftiges. Hy beoð
>     *Modern English*
>     who are in length hundred:GEN feet:GEN long and fifty:GEN they are
> - greate swa stænene sweras micle.
>     *Modern English*
>     great as stone pillars great

It appears in early Modern English, before the concept of *century* (i.e. 100 years) was adopted, phrases had to be employed. In *[A Christian directorie guiding men to their salvation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RbwHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22seven%20hundred%20and%20fourteen%20years%20past%22&source=bl&ots=PxGKdnNuLS&sig=BPsQNs1cN11GaSW-Rum7b4qChUI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF8Zex8OrNAhXD0hoKHe3eAL8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22seven%20hundred%20and%20fourteen%20years%20past%22&f=false)*, printed in **1585** the following phrases are used:

> “... complained in their Talmud, that ther seemed to them in thos dayes, **seven hundred & fourtiene years past**, **since Christ** by the scriptures, should have **appeared**;...”
>
> [image]
>
> “... thou hast to remember (loving brother) that for **the space of three hundred years together after Christs departure out of this world**; he sent almost continual temptations, that is to say continual tribulatios affliction ...”
>
> [image]
>   <sub>Many thanks to [@V0ight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336554/what-was-a-century-called-before-it-was-called-century/336563#comment772612_336563) who posted the relevant link</sub>

Today, we might express the first date as the *8th century / 714 A.D*,
while the second, as being the *4th century / 333 A.D* (or [CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era))

Lastly, the [works](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php) of William Shakespeare contain eight citations for “*hundred years*”

> 1. *No, I'll nor sell nor give him: lend you him I will
>
>      For half a hundred years. Summon the town*.
> 2. *Over whose acres walk'd those blessed feet
>
>      Which fourteen hundred years ago were nail'd
>
>      For our advantage on the bitter cross.*
> 3. *Was not devised for the realm of France:
>
>      Nor did the French possess the Salique land
>
>      Until **four hundred one and twenty years**
>
>      After defunction of King Pharamond,*
> 4. *Who died within the year of our redemption
>
>      **Four hundred twenty-six**; and Charles the Great
>
>      Subdued the Saxons, and did seat the French
>
>      Beyond the river Sala, **in the year
>
>      Eight hundred five**. Besides, their writers say,
>
>      King Pepin, which deposed Childeric,*
> 5. *Ay, that I do; and have done any time these three 
>      hundred years*.
> 6. *As in a vault, an ancient receptacle,
>
>      Where, for these many hundred years, the bones
>
>      Of all my buried ancestors are packed:*
> 7. *Traitors, away! he rests not in this tomb:
>
>      This monument five hundred years hath stood,
>
>      Which I have sumptuously re-edified:
>
>      Here none but soldiers and Rome's servitors
>
>      Repose in fame; none basely slain in brawls:*

Comment: So, what you mean is that before "century"  entered common usage the expression used was "hundred years"?

Comment: @Josh61: that's what Shakespeare seems to have used. *"those holy fields Over whose acres walk'd those blessed feet 
Which fourteen hundred years ago were nail'd 
For our advantage on the bitter cross."* German has *Jahrhundert*, but there doesn't seem to have been a corresponding compound word in English.

Comment: I believe ordinal dates  e.g. 12th century, were expressed as "Twelve hundred years after the birth of our Lord" or words to that effect. I haven't done any searches, but that's my hunch. Either that or the Latin word *seculum* was used.

Comment: here's an instance of 'hundred years after': [1577](https://goo.gl/V3F0ZZ), [1586](https://goo.gl/FAUyiO) ..
put it in your answer if you'd like. And here are some of just 'hundred years': [1585](https://goo.gl/ob8HhN), [1586](https://goo.gl/MLWlKL), [1596](https://goo.gl/uT0Lnh)

Comment: @V0ight thanks, I think I'll wait until tomorrow morning before editing though. I don't think I could read all the links and then post something coherent at this late hour. But definitely, will look at the links.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A ~ no problem, at your leisure. The 'hundred years after' in the first link is in the title of the book itself btw (forgot to mention)

Comment: @Mari Lou A ~ the second 1586 link looks like a more recent publication, so may have made a mistake there. The 1585 link definitely is the real Early Modern though, and has 6 instances of 'hundred years'. Only 4 of those instances are highlighted in yellow for some reason. You have to click 'view all' to show all instances.

Comment: @V0ight thank you for checking, but don't worry, I think I already know which citation to use. Tomorrow I'll check the date's authenticity, Google Books is not infallible.

Comment: Very nice research! What triggered the used of "century" especially in reference  ordinal dates (14th century) remains a mystery. ColinFine refers to "a view of history" that arose in those years (17th century) but didn't give more details. Probably a subject  for a future question.

Answer (score 6):

The Latin word for "century" was "[saeculum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsaeculum)". Is that old enough?

From: *Charlton T. Lewis, Charles Short, A Latin Dictionary*

The OED has a reference for "secle" in an English text from about 1533. That makes it more than a century earlier than the earliest reference for "century".

Comment: Etruscans were not English people... and although Latin was spoken in Medieval Britain, I don't think it's appropriate to call it *English*. The OP is asking for Middle and Early Modern English equivalent of *century* meaning 100 years.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. The OED has a reference for "secle" in an English text from about 1533. That makes it more than a century earlier than the earliest reference for "century": exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @ab2. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I have had to omit your reference to Wikipedia because of its incorrect statement that the term "saeculum" was used by Etruscans. Typical wiki-nonsense in fact.

Comment: The you should add the OED citation, I would be very interested to read it. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the venerable OED.

Comment: > A [saeculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saeculum) is not normally used for a fixed amount of time, in common usage it stands for about 90 years. It can be divided into four "seasons" of approximately 22 years each; these seasons represent youth, rising adulthood, midlife, and old age. The word has evolved within Romance languages (and Swedish) to mean "century" –Wiki

Comment: @Mazura. The Roman author Varro (1st century BC) says explicitly that "the period of 100 years was called saeclum" (saeclum spatium annorum centum vocārunt). Wikipedia is wrong to claim that this meaning "evolved within Romance languages".